# Graph endpoints working in Graph API Explorer but not in my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access the `read_mailbox` Open Graph API endpoint, which was deprecated in v2.4. The app I'm using is fairly old and is able to access v2.3, where `read_mailbox` was last available. There was a 90-day deprecation on `read_mailbox` from v2.3 to v2.4, but I can still access the endpoint in my Graph API Explorer.

When I request that scope from my app, I get "Invalid_scopes". Why am I able to access it in my Graph API Explorer, but not in my app, which is able to access v2.3 of the API?

EDIT: It definitely works in my Explorer. My app name is L7Weenie, I'm using v2.3 and requesting the `me/inbox` endpoint:

[image]

Comment: Which accesstoken do you use en Graph API Explorer? The permission is deprecated. You will not be able to use it

Comment: I'm granting the `read_mailbox` permission, using the `me/inbox` Graph API endpoint under v2.3 and it works.

Comment: Which App is selected?

Comment: Graph API Explorer

Comment: Select your app and you will see it doesn't work

Comment: My app was made when v2.3 was available, so I still have access to it. So it does work in the Explorer, but not on my device.

Comment: No the permission has been deprecated in all versions.

Comment: Ok, I filed a bug for Graph API Explorer so someone can fix it. You will not be able to use it in an app

Comment: Poor you. Even if it worked in API v2.3 that would have stopped working 1 year from now

Comment: I'm just trying to use it for a terrible ideas hackathon this weekend. I was going to make an app that notified you when nobody messaged you :)